# Definition of the Domain of a Function when the sets are the elements

Tags: functions, notation

In case I have a function that calculate the normalized distance of elements in two sets $A$ and $B$ I can define the function as $\mathrm{elementDistance} : A \times B \rightarrow [0,1]$.

But if I want to define another function to calculated the normalized distance of the sets (summing all the distances obtained by the other function), could I defined it in the same way as $\mathrm{setDistance} : A \times B \rightarrow [0,1]$ ?

Or would it create an ambiguity since $\mathrm{setDistance}$ is the distance of $A$ to $B$ and not their elements distance $(a_i,b_j)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When we have a function $f: X\rightarrow Y$, it means that $f(x)$ is defined for every $x\in X$. Hence you are using correct notation only in the first situation where the distance function is defined for every $x\in A\times B$, while in the second case is the distance function is not defined for any $x\in A\times B$.

If we let $S$ be the set of sets you are interested in, then the second function would properly be defined as $g: S^2\rightarrow [0,1]$. Note that if the only sets you are interested in are $A$ and $B$, then $S=\{A,B\}$.

Comment: I was trying to avoid creating another set, but it seems to be the way then! Thank you!

Another question: if I have an element $a_1$ and have a function that calculates the distance of $a_1$ to all the elements of $B$ and the result is only the maximum distance found, would be right to use $maxDistance : A X B \rightarrow [0,1]$ in this case?

Comment: @user136913 Not quite, you would want to use something like just $A\rightarrow [0,1]$ or $A\times S\rightarrow [0,1]$, because the function is only defined for a particular element in $a\in A$ and a particular set $B\in S$. You would use just $A\rightarrow [0,1]$ if you want the function to only work in the particular case of the set $B$ instead of any set in $S$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to follow your suggestion! One last question, would it be wrong to use the parameters (to let clear the order) in the definition? E.g., $setDistance(A,B) : S^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$ ?

Comment: @user136913 No problem! Unfortunately it would be incorrect to do that. What you would do is something like $setDistance: S^2\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $setDistance(A,B)=\max\limits_{a\in A,\, b\in B}Distance(a,b)$. The order becomes clear when you specify what the function actually is after you have specified the function's domain and codomain.